# VB silverlight for windows phone "DownloadStringAsync"

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hello i am developing application for windows phone and i want to read an xml from the web
so i am using on page loaded event :

`Dim cl As New WebClient
AddHandler cl.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf cl_DownloadStringCompleted
cl.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("demo.com/1.xml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))`

and on cl.DownloadStringCompleted event :

`Dim doc = XDocument.Load("demo.com/1.xml")`

but for some reason i crashes ! 
the bug must be that i have not to use URI : "demo.com/1.xml"  , but some else :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DownloadStringCompleted` event has `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`. You should use the Result property of those args.

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
AddHandler client.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf ClientOnDownloadStringCompleted
client.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://demo.com/xml"))
```

and the handler:

```
Private Sub ClientOnDownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, args As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(args.Result)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `args.Result` the string contents from the request or is it a filename? If it's a string that contains the xml, then you'd want to call `XDocument.Parse` instead of `Load`.